# Why is my Dockerized Browserless-Chrome hanging when a Mediawiki Selenium test causes a new page to be loaded?

Tags: docker, selenium, makefile, puppeteer, mediawiki

### Background

I have a makefile which fetches and spins up a Dockerized Mediawiki instance on my local machine, from scratch, with a single `make` command:

https://gitlab.wikimedia.org/mhurd/mediawiki-docker-make

This works fairly well. Please try it!

### Goal

I'd also like to be able to run Mediawiki's Selenium tests (as-is) in Docker containers and watch them execute "live", with the makefile, again, making it easy to kick this process off.

### Approach

This work-in-progress branch adds a container for running Mediawiki Selenium tests, and a [browserless-chrome](https://hub.docker.com/r/browserless/chrome) container so you can watch and debug the tests "live", as they run:

https://gitlab.wikimedia.org/mhurd/mediawiki-docker-make/-/tree/selenium

As you can see from the top of this branch's readme, after running `make` to spin everything up, running `make runseleniumtests` kicks the tests off. When doing so a browser window is automatically opened which lets you see the Selenium tests which are running in the browserless-chrome container. This works... to a point.

### Problem

Unfortunately, after a few tests are seen to be running, I'm seeing this error:

`Protocol error (Input.dispatchMouseEvent): Target closed.`

I suspect the way the browserless-chrome container manages its Chrome sessions may be to blame, as it appears the error is happening when a test causes a new page to be loaded, but I'm not sure.

Any ideas appreciated, and please try it yourself - the whole point of the makefile is to make spinning this up from scratch super simple. It only takes a couple commands and you should be able to see the tests running and the resulting error. Thanks!

### Misc

Running `curl -s http://127.0.0.1:3000/sessions | python3 -m json.tool` on the host machine after attempting to run the tests shows there are multiple browserless-chrome sessions, but I'm unsure how to make it behave more like a non-dockerized setup - which has no problem with tests which cause page loads.

In email communication with Browserless support, they mention seeing similar issues but haven't been able to track down why:

> It seems to be that the root cause may be due to "click" events aren't
> working properly when your viewing the live debugger. Can you confirm
> that if you don't open the live viewer, it allows the test to progress
> and eventually throws new errors regarding selectors not being found? (Edit: I did)
>
> I've also run into this live debugger behavior before and in my
> experience I stopped watching the live debugger, and since I couldn't
> see which selector it wasn't finding I exported a screenshot and in
> that particular case, it ended up being an issue with my viewport,
> since the viewport in the remote session was smaller, the styles
> rendered differently then locally on my machine, when I set the
> viewport size, the selectors were found - but then again, that was my
> particular issue, might not be yours.
>
> But yes, for some odd reason when you view live sessions, you can run
> into this odd issue which we haven't been able to understand.